# MS Word populate text after is inserted via VBA form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, populate, bookmarks

I have created word macro enabled template.
At opening form pops-up and user can fill in form. After pressing OK bookmarks inside document are  updated and shown.
What I need is to populate entered values trough entire document on multiple locations. I have tried cross-referencing bookmarks but they are not updated with values entered in form.

[image of opening form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whYep.png)

```
Private Sub cancelBut_Click()
    stInfo.Hide
    
End Sub

Private Sub Label11_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OKbut_Click()
    Dim katcest As Range
    Set katcest = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("katcest").Range
    katcest.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Dim katopcina As Range
    Set katopcina = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("katopcina").Range
    katopcina.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Dim zkcest As Range
    Set zkcest = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("zkcest").Range
    zkcest.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    Dim zkopcina As Range
    Set zkopcina = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("zkopcina").Range
    zkopcina.Text = Me.TextBox4.Value
    Dim zkulozak As Range
    Set zkulozak = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("zkulozak").Range
    zkulozak.Text = Me.TextBox5.Value
    Dim povrsina As Range
    Set povrsina = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("povrsina").Range
    povrsina.Text = Me.TextBox6.Value
    Dim vlasnik As Range
    Set vlasnik = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("vlasnik").Range
    vlasnik.Text = Me.TextBox7.Value
    Dim vladresa As Range
    Set vladresa = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("vladresa").Range
    vladresa.Text = Me.TextBox8.Value
    Dim datocevida As Range
    Set datocevida = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("datocevida").Range
    datocevida.Text = Me.TextBox9.Value
    Dim klasa As Range
    Set klasa = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("klasa").Range
    klasa.Text = Me.TextBox10.Value
    Dim urbroj As Range
    Set urbroj = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("urbroj").Range
    urbroj.Text = Me.TextBox11.Value
    Me.Repaint
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer

    ' Find position of extension in file name
    strDocName = ""
    intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
 
    If intPos = 0 Then
 
        ' If the document has not yet been saved
        ' Ask the user to provide a file name
        strDocName = InputBox("Upisi naziv " & _
            "vaseg dokumenta.")
    Else
 
        ' Strip off extension and add ".txt" extension
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        strDocName = strDocName & ".docx"
    End If
 
    ' Save file with new extension
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strDocName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    stInfo.Hide
    infoForm.Show
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the best use of bookmarks.  If you wish to populate the document with test I'd more likely use fields that pull in a custom document property.  SO your form would update the custom document properties and then update the fields in the document to get the current text into the document.

Comment: An additional method to the ones suggested by @freeflow is to use mapped content controls. These have the advantage of not requiring any further action to update the values in the document once you have updated the values in the underlying xml.

Comment: You are not updating the bookmarked ranges. All you're doing is inserting content at that point. Check out to see https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/21845-cross-referencing-bookmarks-populated-userform-word-2010-a.html#post67058, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/36617-replace-named-table-text.html & https://www.msofficeforums.com/127871-post15.html how to update a bookmarked range. Additionally, all you need add for the cross-references to update is ActiveDocument.Fields.Update.

Comment: @macropod I think I understand what you are saying but I'm total newbie in VBA. Where should I put code for bookmark and cross-reference update?

Comment: Every link I posted has everything you need...